# How can I mute the YouTube app while playing music on another player?

Tags: music, youtube, volume-control, media-player, mute

I do love to listen to music while watching text YouTube videos, but I can't because YouTube can't be muted.

I use the respect audio focus in [Musicolet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.krosbits.musicolet&hl=en) Music Player.

I have tried App Volume Control but it did nothing!

Comment: Can you please add which is your device brand ?

Comment: it's huawei....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play video in browser instead of youtube app. In browser you can mute the audio.

If your browser launched youtube app when clicked on video link, you need to copy the url and paste it inside the search box - youtube video will load in browser.

Comment: i already know this trick .. but chrome youtube is so poor compared to youtube app...... what browser do you recommend me that feels similar to youtube app

Comment: Try Firefox lite

Comment: ok thanks ..... but i will wait a little bit to see if i can get any better answer if i didn't ..i will accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try a couple alternative apps. They have some advanced features that the official youtube app lacks.

NewPipe: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/

Skytube: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/free.rm.skytube.oss/