# Watching Youtube and listening to music at same time in android phone- Is it possible

Tags: music, youtube, music-player, mute

How can I watch Youtube video (app) muted as well as listen to music in phone's built in music app in any android phone?

It is not a duplicate of this [How can I mute the YouTube app while playing music on another player?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203425), I had seen that before. The answer there asks us to watch youtube in browser. but  my question is  watching youtube video in youtube app, while listening to music.

May I know if that is possible?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK

Comment: Hello Roohi. If the answer to the linked question doesn't work for you, you should offer a bounty. The questions are the same so they cannot be treated differently.